# How to identify a calendar entry in MS Outlook using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I have a code that loops through all sent MS Outlook emails and does some procedures on each one of them. My code breaks but if there is a calendar entry in my Sent folder which results in an error.

`Run-time error '13': Type mismatch`.

Do you guys know how to identify if an item in my Sent folder is a calendar entry so I can skip it?.

```
sub test()


Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")


Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Set olFolder = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)

Dim email_cnt As Long: email_cnt = olFolder.Items.Count


for t = 1 to email_cnt

    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set oMail = olFolder.Items.Item(t)        
    'do something;

Next t

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that `oMail.Class = 43` (43 is olMailItem). You also need to avoid looping through all items in a folder (why do you need to do that?) and avoid using multiple dot notation (olFolder.Items.Item) - cache the Items collection in a variable before entering the loop.

Comment: my code is way more complex, i don't loop through all items. I just put a small example up here. Thanks. your solution worked.

Comment: In any case, try to use items.Find/FindNext or Items.Restrict as much as you can: it is lot more efficient than *any* kind of looping.